# Encoding Azure postgres dbstring for ruby in yaml

Tags: postgresql, azure, kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to use the following bit of config in a helm deployment config and having some issues with the encoding to be used in ruby files.  I had to encode the forward slashes and the @ sign to get it to work manually in the config.

I'm now trying to parameterise the connection and passing it in via this environment variable declared in the deployments file.

When this value is entered it breaks the deployment.

```
name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
         env:
         - name: DB_STRING
           value: "postgresql:\/\/mydbuser%40postgresql-dbserver:mypassword@postgresql-dbserver:5432\/mydatabasename"
```

Anyone any ideas on how I can use this connection value without breaking my yaml.  Removing the \ and %40 works.

Comment: Could you please include in your question how **exactly** the connection string should look like in your `Pod` in the `env` variable?

Comment: among many ways, you can just have it urlencoded from the browser console and then just use it there. another way is to have it in k8s secret , which usually is base64 encoded, and you can directly mount that in the env, that would be decoded and used then.